# Приведение слов к нормальной форме на Java

Tags: java, pymorphy2, морфология

Есть проект на java. Возникла необходимость в одном из модулей приводить слова к нормальной форме. Слова в основном на русском языке. Похожую адекватную библиотеку знаю на python - pymorphy2. Но необходим аналог на java. Слышал что-то про Jmorphy2, но ни как подключать её, никакой другой внятной информации по ней не нашёл. Может кто подскажет решение данной проблемы.

Comment: Jmorphy2 можно установить через maven: https://github.com/drxaos/jmorphy2-lucene .  Примеры использования можно в тестах посмотреть: https://github.com/drxaos/jmorphy2-lucene/blob/master/src/test/java/company/evo/jmorphy2/MorphAnalyzerTest.java

Comment: @insolor, При добавлении в pom зависимости maven в idea выдает следующую ошибку: Could not find artifact company.evo:jmorphy2-lucene:pom:0.2.0 in central

Comment: Там не только в dependencies нужно добавлять, но и репозиторий в repositories. Т.е. должны быть задействованы оба фрагмента кода из Usage: https://github.com/drxaos/jmorphy2-lucene#usage

Comment: @insolor, пришлось добавить не только репозиторий, но и все зависимости pom https://github.com/drxaos/jmorphy2-lucene/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: @insolor, это нормально?

Comment: По идее нет, попробуйте написать issue автору репозитория